# Category/Product Shipping Restriction

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

I am very new in magento and cracking my head for a week now. I would like to modify the checkout where some products/categories are not allowed to be shipped to some countries. I have seen a script online (thanks to the owner), it works fine with the default checkout page but it hangs when using a checkout extension. This is the Onepage Code, could you please enlighten me of what might be the best approach for this? Or what class to extend to override the checkout extension?

```
    <?php
       class Prohibited_Model_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage {


    protected $Restricted_Countries = array(
        'SA', // Country Codes
        'CA'
    );

    protected $Restricted_Categories = array(
        62, // Category IDs
        30,
        40
    );

    protected $Error_Message = 'Shipping of these products are not available for this country.';

    public function saveShippingMethod($shippingMethod)
    {
        $quote = $this->getQuote();
        $country = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getCountry();
        if(in_array($country, $this->Restricted_Countries)){
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
                foreach ($this->Restricted_Categories as $cat_id) {
                    if(in_array($cat_id, $product->getCategoryIds())){
                        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->Error_Message);
                        Mage::throwException($this->Error_Message);
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return parent::saveShippingMethod($shippingMethod);
    }
}
```

This is the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Prohibited>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Prohibited>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <prohibited>
                 <class>Prohibited_Model</class>
            </prohibited>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <type_onepage>Prohibited_Model_Onepage</type_onepage>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the issue is triggered by the re-write conflict of your restrict extension and the checkout module. They both are trying to rewrite the same base class `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage` and only one manages to do that. You should fix this conflict by yourself or contact the developer of custom checkout module, that you are using. Search for classes in your projects’ checkout module, that were inherited from `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage` or look for the rewrite like this:

`<checkout>
 <rewrite>
 <type_onepage>`

in the `config.xml` of checkout module to find the class you need. Then just compare the method `saveShippingMethod()` and transfer the logic to one of the classes (or create the 3rd one). If your checkout module is in the code pull community, you can copy its class with the complete structure (path) to the code pull local and add the missing logic to it (restrict). But be careful when using this solution. Because after each module upgrade you will have to manually correct it and correlate changes to your new file (in code pull local).

It would be easier to help you, if you provide your `config.xml` file and class, that rewrites `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage` in your checkout module.